# Can't install ISLR package

Tags: r, install.packages

This is the code I ran:

```
install.packages(ISLR);
```

And this was the response:

```
>Error in install.packages : object 'ISLR' not found
```

Any advice?

Comment: You need quotes: `install.packages("ISLR")`.

Comment: Thank you, it was a silly thing to miss. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. Use quotes `install.packages('ISLR')`.
2. Make sure your internet connection available.
3. If you're getting `package is not available as binaries`, update
   your R to the current version.
4. After successfull installation, call `library('ISLR')` to load
   package.