# How do I install.packages corrplot in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-corrplot

I'm getting errors trying to use `install.packages(corrplot)` in RStudio:

```
library(corrplot)
```

> Error in library(corrplot) : there is no package called 'corrplot'

```
install.packages(corrplot)
```

> Error in install.packages : object 'corrplot' not found

What am I doing wrong?

[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsGAc.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install ISLR package in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30838177/cant-install-islr-package-in-r)

Comment: should be `install.packages('corrplot')`

Answer (score 8):

You need to put it in quotes.

```
install.packages("corrplot")
```

Then you can load it.

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/install.packages.html